# Using a map in range of an OPTIONAL MATCH in Neo4j cypher

Tags: python, neo4j, nosql, cypher, mapping

I'm building a Python Application which uses a Neo4j database to analyse word relationships. I am trying to query words which are neighboring in a specific hop range. I'm using Flask for the REST calls and the neo4j Driver for Python for querying. My current approach looks like this:

```py
def get_word(title, neighborhood_right_range):
    db = get_db()
    results = db.run("MATCH (word:Word {title:$title}) "
                     "OPTIONAL MATCH (word)-[:IS_NEIGHBORING*1..$neighborhood_right_range]-(word2:Word) WHERE NOT word2.title=$title "
                     "MATCH (t:Text)-[:CONTAINS]->(word:Word) "
                     "MATCH (t)-[:CONTAINS]->(word2) "
                     "RETURN word.title as title "
                     ", collect(DISTINCT word2.title) as neighbors "
                     "LIMIT 1", {"title": title, "neighborhood_right_range": neighborhood_right_range})
    result = results.single()
    return Response(dumps(word_service.format_word(result)),
                    mimetype="application/json")
```

and results in this:

```py
neobolt.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: Parameter maps cannot be used in MATCH patterns (use a literal map instead, eg. "{id: {param}.id}") (line 1, column 76 (offset: 75))
"MATCH (word:Word {title:$title}) OPTIONAL MATCH (word)-[:IS_NEIGHBORING*1..$neighborhood_right_range]-(word2:Word) WHERE NOT word2.title=$title MATCH (t:Text)-[:CONTAINS]->(word:Word) MATCH (t)-[:CONTAINS]->(word2) RETURN word.title as title , collect(DISTINCT word2.title) as neighbors LIMIT 1"
```

I've tried to use the suggested literal map but couldn't figure out the right way to use it in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can parameterise parts of the pattern that would affect how the query is compiled.

From [the docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/#cypher-parameters-introduction):

> Parameters cannot be used for the following constructs, as these form part of the query structure that is compiled into a query plan:
>
> - property keys; so, MATCH (n) WHERE n.$param = 'something' is invalid
> - relationship types
> - labels

You could instead not use a parameter for `neighbourhood_right_range` but embed that value into the query using normal Python string interpolation or concatenation:

```
results = db.run("MATCH (word:Word {title:$title}) "
                 "OPTIONAL MATCH (word)-[:IS_NEIGHBORING*1.." + neighborhood_right_range + "]-(word2:Word) WHERE NOT word2.title=$title "
                 "MATCH (t:Text)-[:CONTAINS]->(word:Word) "
                 "MATCH (t)-[:CONTAINS]->(word2) "
                 "RETURN word.title as title "
                 ", collect(DISTINCT word2.title) as neighbors "
                 "LIMIT 1", {"title": title})
```

Be aware that if neighborhood_right_range is user-controlled in any way you'll need to sanitise that input as concatenating queries this way can be a security risk.